# How does Containing affect MongoDB query performance?

Tags: spring, mongodb, performance, sql-like

I have the following query method.

```
findAllByProfile_UserIdContainingAndOrigin
```

There is an index for profile.userId but the query is extremely slow.
I suspect that because of the Containing keyword the index is not being used efficiently since it has to check the profile.userId property of all documents for similar properties.

Is my suspicion correct? Is there a way to test this conclusively in a dev environment?

Clarification:
The method has no body, it's a query method that is automatically converted into a query.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/query-methods.html

Example of the executed query:

{ "profile.userId" : { "$regularExpression" : { "pattern" : ".*12345.*", "options" : ""}}, "origin" : "user"} fields: Document{{}}

Comment: How can one answer your question without knowing the content of your method?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit 
The method has no body, it's a query method.
It is automatically derived from the method name.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/query-methods.html

Comment: Check the query execution plan. I don't think $regularExpression, uses index at all

Comment: @CharchitKapoor I checked in MongoDBCompass and it increments the index usage count whenever this query is run. Could it be that this increases even if the index isn't being used?

Comment: Maybe. Can you check the output of explain, as mentioned here. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/

Comment: @CharchitKapoor
Using this
```
.explain().find({ "profile.userId" : { "$regex" : ".12345."}})
```
I got this in the result
```
indexName: 'profile.userId_1
```

Comment: Ok, the index is getting used, but since it's a regex match it might not be that optimal. Try creating an index on `origin` field.

Comment: Better yet create a compound index on origin and profile.userId

Comment: @CharchitKapoor The origin field has the same value in 99% of the documents, would it help to include it in the index? The only truly unique value is the userId. If the regex is not properly using the index as I suspected, then the solution would be to remove the regex.

Comment: Yes, regex match should be removed, in that case